# Creating Folder and adding Files in it

Tags: php

I want to create a folder and file when submitting a form.But I want the file to be created into the folder.
The code is creating Folder and file.But I want to create the file  on the folder that was created.

```
<?php

mkdir($_POST['text_name']);
fopen("newfile.html", "w");
?>
```

Comment: `fopen("dir_name/newfile.html", "w");` try this :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$_POST['text_name'].'/newfile.html', "w");
```

Answer (score 0):

In php script you can use `` to call shell. Take care here is not ''.  You've to create the dir before you create the file, with a deeper depth of the path use the -p parameter for mkdir. And I don't think this is a good way to use the post text_name for the dir path, for there may be some special chars that will cause errors, when you move the file in some action.

Hope this helps.

```
<?php
  $dir = $_POST['text_name'];
  `mkdir -p $dir`;
  fopen($dir."/newfile.html", "w");
?>
```